# Blackberry signing application in blackberry device?

Tags: blackberry

Actually i am signing my all applications and using it nicely but just few minutes back i got error  General Failure Please try again. Server unavailable.while signing the app.
I surfed on google and i came to know that this error can occur if there is some changes regarding proxy server in the environment. But dont know what's the Problem.
Please help
Thanks, in advance

Comment: when u tried to sign app, internet is available or not ?

Comment: its available and now also i m facing the same problem please help

Answer (score 2):

Blackberry signing servers sometimes are down. For maintenance purposes, connection issues, etc.

There's a site that shows the current state of Blackberry signing servers, link is below:

[Is the signing server down?](http://isthesigningserverdown.com/)

Comment: i went through this url previously but wat's the solution please help

Comment: Uninstall java sdk and java jre from your computer, restart it. Download the latest java sdk from oracle.com and install it to the same folder(s). Restart computer and try to sign your application again.

Comment: sorry but i found the problem and i managed to solve it thnks its the problem of proxy server

Comment: That's a bit strange when use of a proxy leads to General Protection Failure.

Answer (score 0):

This might helpful for you,

In Java ME same concept is there, you can not read the SMS from inbox directly. so Nokia has create one API called [APIBridge.jar](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/J2ME_API_Bridge_Interface). It Bridges the gape between Lower API and Higher API.

Try it your self. That link contains all the detail.